# Delete a row from cursor while using the cursor

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

I have a cursor that iterates through my temporary table. While it's iterating, I want to check a condition and delete some rows depending on the condition (I will be deleting rows that the iterator has not reached yet).

I tried deleting rows from the table the cursor is iterating (so the temp table), but no success, I can see them in the `Messages panel` (I print its name).

Is it possible to delete rows from the table a cursor is iterating in SQL-Server ? If it's not, what are my alternatives ?

Basically, the temp table contains tree-like data and depending on the value of a column, I need to delete its children (and grand-children and so on) if it does not fit a criteria.

```
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR
FOR (SELECT * FROM #test) ORDER BY Path


DECLARE
    @Id AS INTEGER,
    @Name AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Path AS VARCHAR(MAX)

OPEN cursor_name;
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @Id, @Name, @Path;
PRINT @Name

DELETE FROM #test 
WHERE
    Path LIKE '%76939%'

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @Id, @Name, @Path;
        PRINT @Name
    END;

CLOSE cursor_name;
DEALLOCATE cursor_name;
```

#EDIT

Here is more detail on the problem. We have data structured like a tree list. Every item has multiple columns that specify some characteristics the row. Those characteristics can be inherited or not (if `InheritanceFlag` is 1, then it's inherited, if it's 0, then it is not).

So, when a user makes a change, we need to propagate the change to its children, depending on the said flag. If one of its child has the `InheritanceFlag` set to 0, then it won't change its value and neither will its children. I wanted to remove those rows with the cursor using the path.

Here is the data that I have. `ParentID` is the ID of its parent.  In this case, suppose we are editing the item 76938, thus we are looking at its children. The `ToEdit` column is what I'm looking to create; with it, I can filter the rows and directly change the characteristic column to the new value.

```
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| ID    | ParentID |  Name |           Path          | InheritanceFlag | ToEdit |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76938 | NULL     |   1   |         (76938)         | 1               | X      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76942 | 76938    |  1.1  |     (76938)\(76942)     | 1               | 1      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76952 | 76942    | 1.1.1 | (76938)\(76942)\(76952) | 0               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76961 | 76942    | 1.1.2 | (76938)\(76942)\(76961) | 1               | 1      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76943 | 76938    |  1.2  |     (76938)\(76943)     | 1               | 1      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76944 | 76938    |  1.3  |     (76938)\(76944)     | 0               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76946 | 76944    | 1.3.1 | (76938)\(76944)\(76946) | 1               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76947 | 76944    | 1.3.2 | (76938)\(76944)\(76947) | 0               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76948 | 76944    | 1.3.3 | (76938)\(76944)\(76948) | 1               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76945 | 76938    | 1.4   | (76938)\(76945)         | 1               | 1      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
```

Comment: You can `DELETE` inside a `CURSOR` yes, however, the real question is *why* are you using a `CURSOR` in the first place. A `CURSOR` is an iterative task, and SQL Server (and other RDBMS) perform poorly at such tasks. An RDBMS is designed to complete set-based tasks. What is the true goal of the above, and why aren't you using a set based approach?

Comment: It's kinda hard to explain but I'll gve it a shot. We have data structured like a tree list. There a characteristic (multiple columns) that can be inherited from a parent or not. We have a INT flag that tell us that (each bit gives the inheritance setting for one column). So i need to propagate a change on one (or multiple) characteristics and I'm using a cursor so when I see that a row does not inherit from its parent, I need to remove all its children (we have a path column, so a simple `WHERE path like ...` suffices. I really don't see how not to use a cursor in this case.

Comment: I think you'll need a dynamic cursor.

Comment: An rCTE could well work for what you're after. Sample data and expected results will greatly help us help you.

Comment: Ok give me a second, I will build up something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete from the underlying table and have the rows removed from future FETCHes if the cursor is DYNAMIC, and the query that defines the cursor doesn't require a spool, effectively turning it into a STATIC cursor.

In your code sorting by the unindexed VARCHAR(MAX) prevents the cursor from seeing any changes in the underlying table.

EG this

```
drop table if exists #test
go
create table #test(id integer, name varchar(max), path varchar(1000), index ix_path (path))
insert into #test(id,name,path) values (1,'a','0000000'),(2,'b', '0769391'),(3,'c', '1768391')

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR DYNAMIC
FOR SELECT * FROM #test ORDER BY path


DECLARE
    @Id AS INTEGER,
    @Name AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Path AS VARCHAR(MAX)

OPEN cursor_name;
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @Id, @Name, @Path;
PRINT @Name

print 'deleting'
DELETE FROM #test 
WHERE
    Path LIKE '%76939%'

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @Id, @Name, @Path;
    if @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0  break
    PRINT @Name
END;

CLOSE cursor_name;
DEALLOCATE cursor_name;
```

outputs

```
(3 rows affected)
a
deleting

(1 row affected)
c
```

Comment: I added the index on `path` and it works, but I'm not sure why. Care to explain ?

Comment: When you request a DYNAMIC cursor for a query where one can't be created, you get a static cursor instead.  Run `select * from sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@spid)` to see what kind of cursor was actually created.  The index on `path` allows SQL to build a query plan that orders the rows by `path` in-place, and so can use a DYNAMIC cursor.

Comment: ohh ok I get it. Thanks a lot !